# Converting IP2LocationRecord to Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ip2location

Is there a way to use IP2Location `database.get_all()` and convert the results into a Pandas DataFrame? I am really lost and confused as to how to do it.

I have gotten an error `AttributeError: 'IP2LocationRecord' object has no attribute 'values'`.

The values I obtained

```
{'ip': '104.145.231.146', 'country_short': 'US', 'country_long': 'United States of America', 'region': 'New York',
 'city': 'Buffalo', 'latitude': 42.886452, 'longitude': -78.878372, 'zipcode': '14201', 'timezone': '-05:00'}
```

Expected outcome

```
     ip                 country_short    country_long        ....       zipcode      timezone
0    104.145.231.146    US               United States of America       14201        -05:00
```

Comment: try  `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(database.get_all(),orient='index').T`

Comment: I've gotten a TypeError. ```TypeError: object of type 'IP2LocationRecord' has no len()```

Comment: we dont know what `IP2LocationRecord` is so cannot say whats the issue. Your question should be edited to include all details. or atleast to an extent which is reproducible, the above code worked for ṭhe values you obtained, assuming the type is a dictionary